# How to display multiple values in every option tag?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm trying to display multiple values in every option tag. I read some questions and answer here with the same issue I have, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840366/having-multiple-values-within-an-option-tag). But it's not working on my side. The data of option tag will dynamically created with mysql.

How to fix this? Thanks in advance!

E.g.

```
<option value="data 1,data 2, data 3....">Text 1</option>
<option value="data 6,data 7, data 8....">Text 2</option>
```

My current form:

```
$results_streets = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT streets,stores FROM table WHERE streets IN ("Street 1") ORDER BY streets ASC', OBJECT);

<form action="" name="formName">
<div>
<select>
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" value="Select by Street">Select by Street</option>
    <?php
    foreach($results_streets as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['streets_list']) && $_POST['streets_list'] == $option->streets)
            echo '<option name="streets_list" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->stores .'">'. $option->streets .'</option>';
     };
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: try like this :`<option values="data 1:data 2: data 3:....">Text 1</option>`

Comment: So, what does _"But it's not working on my side"_ mean? If you show us how you tried to implement it, we might be able to help you solve the issue.

Comment: @prakashtank, the data is dynamically generated with mysql

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, the code is already in the question (at the bottom)

Comment: you can do string replace right ? str_replace(", ",':',$option->stores) like this

Comment: That code is simply echoing some, for us, unknown string from the database. You need to explain what `$option->stores` contains, what  `data 1, data 2` etc represents and how it should be grouped.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, `$option->stores` contain all stores in that street

Comment: please follow this URl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245967/can-an-option-in-a-select-tag-carry-multiple-values i hope it is help for you

Comment: @Dipali, but data in that question are inputted manually.

Comment: can you please share which format your data is coming

Comment: here `$results_streets = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT streets,stores FROM table WHERE streets IN ("Street 1") ORDER BY streets ASC', OBJECT);`

Comment: use print_r($results_streets); then check output

Comment: i did. and it displayed all streets and stores in an array format

Comment: ok when you put dynamic variable in your option tag,  then what it displays in your option value

Comment: the store, but its only display 1 value. `<option value="Store 1">Street 1</option><option value="Store 2">Street 1</option>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the attribute for the option tag isn't `values`. Try instead `value`, so like this:

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="data 1,data 2, data 3....">Text 1</option>
    <option value="data 6,data 7, data 8....">Text 2</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$results_streets = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT streets,stores FROM table WHERE streets IN ("Street 1") ORDER BY streets ASC', OBJECT);

<form action="" name="formName">
<div>
<select name='streets_list'>
    <option class="filter_by" value="Select by Street">Select by Street</option>
    <?php
    $values = "";
    foreach($results_streets as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['streets_list']) && $_POST['streets_list'] == $option->streets){
            $values.=$option->stores."|";
       } 
     }
    echo '<option class="filter_by" selected value="'. $values .'">Street 1</option>';
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, typo error. How to display multiple values in one option tag dynamically from mysql?

Comment: I think your php code is okay. Do you set the name attribute in the select tag? Because in the second code the name attribute is in the option tag.

Comment: yes, it's already set. but how to put all values in one option tag? E.g. `<option value="Store 1, Store 2,....">Street 1</option>` instead of `<option value="Store 1">Street 1</option> <option value="Store 2">Street 2</option>`

Comment: it's not working, i tried this `$values = "";
    foreach($results_streets as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['mall_list']) && $_POST['streets_list'] == $option->streets)
            $values.=$option->stores."|";
     };
    echo '<option class="filter_by" selected value="'. $values .'">'.$option->streets.'</option>';` there's no value

Comment: i tried this also, `$values = "";
    foreach($results_streets as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['streets_list']) && $_POST['streets_list'] == $option->streets)
            $values.=$option->stores."|";
    echo '<option class="filter_by" selected value="'. $values .'">'.$option->streets.'</option>';
    };` but the value of option is blank

Comment: I updated again my answer. Is there really data in the option value? Try var_dump in the foreach loop.